# The error of npm install as ''console.error(`a bug known to break npm. "

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

Followed by this [post](https://changelog.com/posts/install-node-js-with-homebrew-on-os-x), I have already installed the Node.JS (9.4.0).

```
$brew install node      
$node -v                                                                                   
$v0.12.7
```

Then, `npm install -g grunt-cli` for test. The error shows like this:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js:28
        console.error(`a bug known to break npm. Please update to at least ${r
                      ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:19:21
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:92:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
```

I don't know the erro here, and how to fix it.

Any comments would be appreciated

Comment: *"...I have already installed the Node.JS (9.4.0)."* What you show immediately after that statement shows that you get Node 0.12.7, not Node 9.4.0, when you type `node`. So probably an issue with your path.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have also mentioned that. I'll add the path.

Answer (score 4):

You're using an old version of Node.js which doesn't support template literals.

Upgrade Node to the [latest version](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and you'll be fine.